# Type punning in C using union

Tags: c, language-lawyer, unions, type-punning

Consider the following code:

```
union u{
    int i;
    long j[2];
};

int main(void){
    union u *u = malloc(sizeof *u);
    u->i = 10;
    printf("%li\n", u->j[0]);
}
```

I want to explain the legitimacy of the code with `6.5`:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types:
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> [...]
>
> — an
>   aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types
>   among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate
>   or contained union), or

Applying this to the example above we have:

1. `u->i = 10;` gives `u->i` object to have effective type `int`.
2. The lvalue `u` has a `union` type which contains a member of type `int`.
3. The object `u->j[0]` having unspecified value is accessed using the lvalue `u` of the `union u` type having a member of the type `int`.
4. Applying the quote `6.5` we have that there is no UB here.

**QUESTION:** Is such reasoning correct? Or it contains some fault?

Comment: Regardless of aliasing rules, whether `long` is the same size as `int` is implementation-dependent, so `u->j[0]` has a risk of accessing uninitialized bytes and thereby encountering trap values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But _When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values._ Unspecified value cannot be a trap as per `3.19.3`

Comment: That says the **bytes** take on unspecified values. It does not say the objects represented by those bytes take on unspecified values.

Comment: @stantario: incorrect. And bytes might not be a trap but the value that they form can be.

Comment: @EricPostpischil @AnttiHaapala Understood. So what's the use-case of this point about `union`s?

Comment: The C standard’s wording about the aliasing rules is unfortunately imprecise about aggregates. I do not believe it is correct to claim that, because `u->j[0]` accesses the `j[0]` element of the `j` member through a union `*u` that includes a type compatible with the `int` object that was written to previously, it satisfies the rule. When accessing `u->j[0]`, we are accessing an aggregate and a member of that aggregate and an element of that member. The wording in the standard does not properly explain how to apply the rule to this.

Comment: The rule that is apt in this case is C 2018 6.5.2.3 3, which says that, for a member access (with `.` or `->`), “The value is that of the named member…” As a footnote there tells us, this means the bytes in the union are, if the member is not the last one stored, reinterpreted as the new type. This is understood to tell us that aliasing through a union is defined by the C standard (as affected by implementation-specific details of how the types are represented).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Do you have an idea why it's just a footnote? I searched through the Standard for "type punning" and the footnote was the only place it was mentioned.

Comment: I do not have information about the committee’s deliberations on this. The 1999 standard has the same normative text about accessing the member but not the footnote. A 2007 draft has the footnote. I might guess that, between the two, there was question about the interpretation, and so the footnote was added, and it was deemed merely a clarification not worthy of changing the normative text.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I found the [DR283](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_283.htm) that seems to clarify the reason of the footnote. `C89` contained _With one exception, if a member of a union object is accessed after a value has been stored in a different member of the object, the behavior is implementation-defined._  at `6.5.2.3#5` which was removed in C99. As specified in the DR the clause I cited above was added to `6.2.6`. So the `type-punning` should probably be implied by the `6.2.6` and the footnote was added to clarify this.

Comment: _The object `u->j[0]` having unspecified value is accessed using the lvalue `u` of the `union u` type_ The type of `u` is "pointer to `union u`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your reasonning is correct.  This is not undefined behavior, but unspecified behavior according to C11, section 6.2.6.1/7 :

> When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the
>   bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that
>   member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.

Section 3.19.3 clarifies what this means:

> **unspecified value:** valid value of the relevant type where this International Standard imposes no requirements on which value is
>   chosen in any instance

This is reminded in **Annex J: Portability Issues**

> **J.1 Unspecified behavior**
>   1 The following are unspecified:
>   — ...
>   — The value of padding bytes when storing values in structures or
>   unions (6.2.6.1). 
>   — The values of bytes that correspond to union
>   members other than the one last stored into (6.2.6.1).
>   — ...

Nothing about accessing union members is specified in J2 which is about undefined behavior

This being said, portability issues can be severe as section 6.2.6.1/6 reminds:

> The value of a structure or union object is never a trap
>   representation, even though the value of a member of the structure or
>   union object may be a trap representation.

A trap representation is an "*object representation that need not represent a value of the object type*" (definition), being understood that "*fetching a trap representation **might perform a trap** but is not required to*" (footnote). So accessing the inactive value may lead to the interruption of the programme, but if it doesn't, it's just that there is no guarantee about it.

Comment: @exnihilo thanks for pointing out! In the middle of the nigtht I was confused by the same naming of the union and the pointer :) I'll edit

Comment: The confusing naming had me do a double-take, too ;)